# Finding the number of arrangement of N people of different height such that K of them are visible from front

Tags: algorithm

How to find the number of ways in which N people of different heights (possibly some have same height) are arranged in a queue such that atmost K are visible when seen from front of the queue. If a person is of height H and is not visible from the front then any shorter(or of equal height) person behind him is not visible from the front. Also, if a person of height H is visible from the front. Then, any person who is behind him and having height less than or equal to H is not visible from the front. Or simply, a person is visible from the front, if and only if, all the person before him are strictly shorter than him.

Example:
if there are three people having height = {1,2,3}
then in the following arrangements:
1->2->3 (1 is in front)
1->3->2
2->1->3
2->3->1
3->1->2
3->2->1
we can see following number of people:
3
2
2
2
1
1
respectively.
Note : The value of N will be of the order of (100). I think we can have a Dynamic programming solution but I am unable to figure it out.
Any help is appreciated a lot.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is a math question. Try http://math.stackexchange.com. Or [read the answer here](http://theory.cs.uvic.ca/inf/perm/LRMaxima.html).

Comment: @RaymondChen I think that the answer is a bit different than the Stirling numbers because people who are the same height are allowed. Thanks for the pointer, though!

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks a lot, I think problem is very similar.

Comment: This is the question of an ongoing contest with a different problem statement(http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/LEMOVIE) but asking the same thing, I request the moderator to lock it.

Answer (score 1):

edit: This doesn't deal with the case where more than one person has the same height.

I think that you can get a recurrence by considering the tallest guy and whether he as at the back of the queue or not. Say we're looking for `n` people and `k` who can be seen.

Suppose the tallest guy is at the end of the queue. He can always be seen so the number of configurations where `k` can see is the number where `k-1` of the remaining `n-1` people can be seen.

Suppose he's not at the end of the queue. Then the guy at the end of the queue can never be seen. So  we need to find the number of ways that `k` people can be seen out of the `n-1` who are not at the end of the queue. But there are `n-1` people who can be at the end of the queue so there will be `n-1` times as many configurations as if we were really looking at a smaller case.

So the recurrence is

> T(n,k) = T(n-1, k-1) + (n-1) * T(n-1, k)

I don't have time to turn it into a dynamic programming solution right now but the boundary conditions, etc. should be pretty simple.

Comment: testuser: I can't get your solution. We are always looking from the front. And how does your solution is handling multiple people having same height ? Have you sorted the people according to their heights or what ?

Comment: @user113936 I missed the part about people with the same height.

Comment: @user113936 I assume that we're just looking for the number of people (not outputting configurations or anything) so there's no need to sort anything, only to evaluate the recurrence.

Comment: Thanks a lot testuser. but still I am trying to get your solution. May be because my question was unclear. Now I have updated it.

Comment: how to solve this question if there are duplicates too? I can't find a solution, I tried a lot. Almost all the day, but can't find a solution.

Comment: Once again I want to thank @testuser as your logic is very strong and worked for me! Though it was not very easy but, a little modification to your logic gives the answer. In stead of thinking about tallest person if you think for the shortest one, you can do it easily! Really , I never thought that this problem is that easy!